# Changing units in Cairo svg surface

Tags: svg, cairo

Cairo SVG surface seems to use points rather than pixels as a default unit; is it possible to somehow globally override this?

I would like to have a rendering code that outputs (possibly) the same thing with PNG and SVG driver -- I could of course add a modifier to all widths and sizes but this seems a bit cumbersome...